# How do I create extended functionalities if Adobe AIR is used, like Adobe did?

Tags: actionscript-3

Basically, I want to create functions and import classes based on whether Adobe AIR is used or not. I've seen Adobe doing this with several classes. So, if you're not running Adobe AIR that's okay, but with Adobe AIR more functions are available to you

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You know at compile time, which plattform you target. So basically i'd create two builds, one for the web and one for air, which include both the dependencies needed. When implementing applications instead of just libraries, you could easily implement different contexts or bootstrapper for your applications (wisely implement against interfaces, not classes).

Comment: No, that is not what I want. I want to create one class which can be used in context. So users just have to import that one class, and the class will figure things out themselves.

For example, with flash.media.Loader class, you can use it on its own with Adobe Flash Player, but if you use Adobe AIR, there is an AIR specific function "cacheAsBitmapMatrix" that you can use